# Docker process suspends and gets killed

Tags: python, r, bash, docker, dockerfile

Like in the topic, docker process suspends and gets killed.
My python project runs bash script whose one of the parts is to run R script which withdraws data from influxdb and then processes it. When the project gets data for a short period of time e.g. 1-5 days, it is not a problem. The whole thing starts with bigger time frames like a couple of weeks. It just slows down so badly so that it takes ages to generate anything (I checked logs) and eventually it gets killed. It’s OK when R script withdraws something about 25mb of data, however 70mb of data is not as easy. Can it be something that Flask+bash+R use too much memory at once or something? Such problem does not appear when invoked outside of docker

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
# Install requirements fot the flask app
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -y && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    r-base \
    r-base-dev \
    r-cran-rgl \
    mutt \
    git \
    texlive-fonts-recommended

# Install requirements fot the flask app
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
```

flask app snippet:

```
@app.route('/send', methods=['POST'])
def send():
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    script = path + '/generate_pdf.sh'
    address = str(request.form['email'])
    start_date = convert_date(str(request.form['start_date']))
    end_date = convert_date(str(request.form['end_date']))
    command = [script, start_date, end_date, address]
    subprocess.run(command)
    return json.dumps({
        'status': 'OK',
        'message': 'The action is completed'
    })
```

generate_pdf.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
start_date="$1"
end_date="$2"
address="$3"
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
report_name="\"$DIR/my_document.pdf\""
R -e "rmarkdown::render('$DIR/generate_document.Rmd', output_file = $report_name)" --args "$start_date" "$end_date"
report_name="$DIR/my_document.pdf"
echo | mutt -s "Generated document" -a $report_name -- "$address"
out=$(rm $report_name)
```

R script snippet:

```
where.clause <- paste0("time >= '", 
                       start.date,
                       "' AND time <= '", 
                       as.character(as.Date(end.date) + days(1)), 
                       "'")
con <- influxdbr::influx_connection(host = "localhost",
                                    port = 8086,
                                    user = "root",
                                    pass = "root")
select.query <- paste0(
  'id, name, surname, car, employment_status'
)
rows <- influx_select(con, db = 'my_db', select.query, from = 'workers',
                         where = where.clause)
rows <- as.data.frame(rows, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
if(is.data.frame(rows) && nrow(rows) == 0) {
  cat('No data could be obtained from the database.', sep = '\n')
  knitr::knit_exit()
}
```

Here are the logs that I got while executing the app, which was suppose to withdraw about 74mb of data.

```
....
label: unnamed-chunk-4 (with options) 
List of 3
 $ echo   : logi FALSE
 $ message: logi FALSE
 $ warning: logi FALSE

Success: (204) No Content
/app/generate_pdf.sh: line 8:    58 Killed
....
```

The application works perfectly outside the docker.

When this command `rows <- influx_select` is invoked, the data is obtained in a raw version. Before it gets cast to dataframe it weights a lot - 24mb, 70 and more.

I manually ran the script inside the docker and the R script went a bit farther:

```
....
label: unnamed-chunk-8 (with options) 
List of 4
 $ echo      : logi FALSE
 $ message   : logi FALSE
 $ fig.align : chr "left"
 $ fig.height: num 7

Quitting from lines 72-76 (generate_document.Rmd) 
Error in system(paste(which, shQuote(names[i])), intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : 
cannot popen '/usr/bin/which 'pdfcrop' 2>/dev/null', probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'
...
```

Comment: You could try using the hosts shared memory `-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm` in your `docker run` command.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately.